# custom picker view animation like action sheet

Tags: iphone

How to animate custom picker view like actionsheet?

```
UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,300,320,300)] autorelease];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:[self view] cache:YES];
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,300.0f,320.0f,325.0f)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: i have a custom view with buttons than picker view how i can display it sliding up from bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer is this for custom picker view but it won't animate like action sheet. But it creates custom picker view.

```
items =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hindi",@"English",nil];
pickerView=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,250,350,350)];
pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75f, 0.75f);
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:view]; 


- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
return [items count];   
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return[items objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you did:

```
UIView *view=[[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,460,320,300)]autorelease];
view.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:[self view] cache:YES];

[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,300)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But have a look at CGRect. Its `(x,y,width,height)`. So you have to use the second parameter (y position) to animate the vertical position of your view.

Comment: this takes uiview up and buttons are down i just want custom view to popup from the bottom in a sliding way. i dont want to bring the custom view at the top.

Comment: aren't your buttons subviews of the view? they should be. But you just need to fix you coordinates. Try `[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,160,320,300)];`